Convert GPS Week and GPS Time of Week to J2000?
I'm new to this, and am trying to convert GPS Time to J2000 time using python and Astropy. Here's what I've come up with:
def gps_week_tow_to_j2000(gps_week, gps_tow):
    gps_epoch = Time('1980-01-06T00:00:00', scale='utc') # GPS Epoch, scale UTC, since UTC = GPS Epoch on 1980-01-06T00:00:00
    j2000_epoch = Time('2000-01-01T12:00:00', scale='tt') # Getting J2000.0 Epoch, scale Terrestrial Time. https://aa.usno.navy.mil/faq/TT#:~:text=The%20epoch%20designated%20%22J2000.,11%3A58%3A55.816%20UTC.
    
    # Since gps_week is counter from gps_epoch, we'll convert it to seconds, and add the time_of_week to it.
    time_since_gps_epoch = gps_week * 7 * 24 * 3600 + gps_tow # Seconds since GPS Epoch in UTC.
    # to get the GPS Time
    gps_time = Time(gps_epoch.utc.jd + time_since_gps_epoch/86400, format='jd', scale='utc') # Time as per GPS, in UTC, format=JD.
    
    j2000_in_seconds = (gps_time - j2000_epoch).sec
    return j2000_in_seconds

gps_week = 2304 
gps_tow = 308536.998852
j2000_seconds = gps_week_tow_to_j2000(gps_week, gps_tow)
print(f"J2000 seconds: {j2000_seconds}")


Result is 763004606.1828591. Is this accurate?

Astropy actually has a GPS format that takes the time since the GPS epoch as an argument.
Also, I would recommend using astropy.units to simplify the conversions.
Using these suggestions, your code can be simplified to:
import astropy.units as u
from astropy.time import Time

def gps_week_tow_to_j2000(gps_week, gps_tow):
  j2000_epoch = Time('2000-01-01T12:00:00', scale='tt')
  t = (gps_week * u.wk) + (gps_tow * u.s)
  gps_time = Time(t, format="gps")
  timedelta = (gps_time - j2000_epoch)
  return timedelta.sec

gps_week = 2304 
gps_tow = 308536.998852
j2000_seconds = gps_week_tow_to_j2000(gps_week, gps_tow)
print(f"J2000 seconds: {j2000_seconds}")

J2000 seconds: 763004588.182852

I think this is different than your code since the line
gps_time = Time(gps_epoch.utc.jd + time_since_gps_epoch/86400, format='jd', scale='utc')

should actually be something like
gps_time = Time(gps_epoch.tai.jd + time_since_gps_epoch/86400, format='jd', scale='tai')

since the UTC timescale takes into account leap seconds, which is probably not what you want.
